# What is the AppleScript Folder Action for moving/deleting a file?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a script that is working fine when I add a file to the folder using:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
```

What is the equivalent when a file is either moved or deleted from that folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

=== edited to answer to comments:

```
on removing folder items from this_folder after losing lost_items
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in lost_items
    set nameOfLostFile to name of (info for item i of lost_items)
end repeat
end removing folder items from
```

Comment: This is almost what I need, only thing is that this returns the trashed file name. I need the name of the original file. How would I do this?

Comment: So if I delete 'file.txt' from the folder, how do I return only that 'file.txt'?

Comment: Thanks! This will get me to where I need, still having an issue with the `    nameOfLostFile` being the 'Trashed' file name; so if I add a file that was there and delete it the name is 'File copy.txt' where the original file was 'File.txt' but I should be able to figure something out.